# Calculating daily return of Stock Portfolio in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, stock

So my goal is to basically create a plot that shows the daily returns of a portfolio over a period of 3 years. my dataset consists of columns consisting of stock tickers and each row symbolizes a date, there is also a date column that is the first column of each row.

The weightings are in a dictionary like this

```
{'ABB': 0.0166,
 'ABG': 0.00164788,
 'ADBE': 0.000178035,
 'ALB': 0.033145842,
 'APD': 0.024828715}
```

and i want to start with initial capital of 20,000

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
portfolio_returns = []
capital = 20000
for (date, row), weight in zip(subset.iterrows(), portfolio_weightings.values()):
    daily_return = (capital * weight) * sum(value for value, weight in zip(row[1:], portfolio_weightings.values()))
    portfolio_returns.append(daily_return)
```

when plotted the returns look approximately correct but I am confused on why each value in portfolio_returns is in the 280,000s. If you could help correct this I would really appreciate it

Comment: Where do you have the number of shares you own of each stock?

Comment: i was wanting to use fractional shares so wanted to buy let's say  for ALB (.0331 *20,000) worth of shares

Comment: So, are you saying you want to use 3.3% of your capital to buy ALB on day #1, at whatever its price is?  If so, then you need to track the number of SHARES you bought, not the percentage of the portfolio.  The number of shares is constant.  Their value is variable.

Comment: If your data is a row for each date (ascending), columns as tickers (plus date first) and values as share price, then you could instead use the following one line of code for portfolio daily returns: `df.set_index("date").div(df.set_index("date").iloc[0]).mul(portfolio_weightings).mul(capital).sum(axis=1).pct_change()`.  This sets the `date` column as the index, rebases so that prices grow from 1, then multiplies by the portfolio weighting and capital - before summing all columns and calculating percentage change (daily returns) for the portfolio.

Comment: If the ticker data is returns, then you need to calculate cumulative probability, so change `.div(...)` to `.add(1).cumprod()` to add 1 to returns and calculate cumulative probability (which will start from 1 if first return is 0) - otherwise rebase with `.div(...)` again for the first row to become 1s.

Answer (score -2):

The issue with your code lies in the calculation of the daily_return variable. In your current implementation, you are multiplying the capital by the weight and then summing the values in the row, which includes the weights again. This leads to an overestimation of the daily returns.

To calculate the daily return correctly, you need to multiply the capital by the weight and then sum the product of each stock's value and its corresponding weight. Here's the corrected code:

```
portfolio_returns = []
capital = 20000

for date, row in subset.iterrows():
    daily_return = capital * sum(row[ticker] * weight for ticker, weight in portfolio_weightings.items())
    portfolio_returns.append(daily_return)
```

In this updated code, we iterate over each row in the subset DataFrame (assuming subset contains the relevant stock values). For each row, we calculate the daily_return by summing the product of each stock's value (row[ticker]) and its corresponding weight (weight), obtained from the portfolio_weightings dictionary.

I've used portfolio_weightings.items() to iterate over both the ticker and weight simultaneously from the portfolio_weightings dictionary.

Now, the portfolio_returns list will contain the correct daily returns, and you can proceed to plot them to visualize the portfolio's performance over time.